# How can we change the size of images in HTML by tag name?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm building an article reading iOS app.Article contains multiple images.
I am unable to change the size of images in html.
 here is my code:-

```
    NSString *url=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:_DetailModal1[3] ];//contain html content.<br>


    NSString *javaScriptStar=@"<script>a = document.getElementsByTagName('img');for (i = 0;i a.length;i++) {a[i].style.maxWidth = '600px';}</script><div style = \"line-height:85px;font-size:55px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;font-weight:400;\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `width`property instead of `maxWidth`. Also your for loop is missing `<` .

Please check [this JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sKp29/1/)

Here is the updated working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
      <img border="0" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS28hGdxjiRyMSuYNKY3ogoqKSZUZFRqlH93apAmZlJ-chii5EG"  
        alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228"/>

<script>
 function myFunction() {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var i =0;
    for (i = 0;i< a.length;i++) 
    {
        a[i].style.width = '1000px';
    }
 }
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Ramshad,I have changed my code but its not working.         <script>a = document.getElementsByTagName('img');for (i = 0;i < a.length;i++) {a[i].style.width = '600px';}</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *url=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:_DetailModal1[3] ];//contain html content.     

    NSString *javaScriptStar=@"<style type=\"text/css\">img { width : 1000px !important; height:500px !important;}</style>";
```